How to configure sshd_config to allow HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa for a specific IP and restrict all other IPs on Ubuntu22.04 Server?
I am running an Ubuntu 22.04 server and need to configure sshd_config to achieve the following:
Allow the use of HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa for a specific IP address. ex. x.x.x.6 , x.x.x.100, x.x.x.150
Restrict or deny the use of HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa for all other IP addresses.
I have tried adding the following lines to my sshd_config file, but it doesn't seem to work as
Match Address x.x.x.6
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Match Address x.x.x.100
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Match Address x.x.x.150
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

What is the correct way to configure sshd_config to meet these requirements? Are there any additional steps or configurations I need to consider? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Note:
Ubuntu Version: 22.04
OpenSSH Version: OpenSSH_8.9p1

AFAIK HostKeyAlgorithms is not in the subset of keywords that may be used in a Match block (per man sshd_config)
